# TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, but it was a set

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**
This is the error message I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users//Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2551, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/mnt/c/Users//Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2531, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/mnt/c/Users//Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/mnt/c/Users//Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/mnt/c/Users//Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1826, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/mnt/c/Users//Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1845, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/mnt/c/Users//Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2173, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a set.
```

**
This is my application.py :**

```
import models
import jwt
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from flask_cors import CORS
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")
models.db.init_app(app=app)

@app.route("/users", methods=["POST"])
def create_user():
    hashed_pw = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(
        request.json["password"]).decode("utf-8")
    try:
        user = models.User(email=request.json["email"], password=hashed_pw,)

        models.db.session.add(user)
        models.db.session.commit()

        encrypted_id = jwt.encode(
            {"user_id": user.id}, os.environ.get("JWT_SECRET"), algorithm="HS256"
        )

        return {"user": user.to_json(), "user_id": encrypted_id}
        # return "ok"

    except Exception as e:
        return {"error" f"{e}"}, 400

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = os.environ.get("PORT") or 5001
    app.run("0.0.0.0", port=port, debug=True)
```

**
This is my models.py:**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String)

    carts = db.relationship("Cart")

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "email": self.email,
            "carts": [c.to_json() for c in self.carts],
        }

class Cart(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "carts"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    item_name = db.Column(db.String)
    item_price = db.Column(db.String)
    item_link = db.Column(db.String)
    item_img = db.Column(db.String)
    checkout_date = db.Column(db.String)
    checkedOut = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "item_name": self.item_name,
            "item_price": self.item_price,
            "item_link": self.item_link,
            "item_img": self.item_img,
            "checkout_date": self.checkout_date,
            "checkedOut": self.checkedOut,
        }
```

While my code still commits to the database successfully, I still get the TypeError and don't receive the json. I don't know where this error lies. This is a project I'm revisiting from before that used to work.

Comment: `{"error" f"{e}"}` is a set, which is not allowed according to the error. I think you mean `{"error": f"{e}"}`?

Comment: That was the problem. I don't know how the colon was removed. Thank you!